# Two conditional probability questions about three chests with two balls each

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> Consider 3 chests. Each chest has 2 balls.
>   **Chest A** has  $\color{red}{both\,\,red}$.
>   **Chest B** $\color{red}{one\,\,red}$ and $\color{blue}{one\,\,blue}$.
>   **Chest C** has $\color{blue}{both\,\,blue}$.
>
> A chest is drawn at random. What is the probability that chest A was drawn given that:
>
> 1. There exists at least $\color{red}{one\,\,red}$.
> 2. A random ball choosen from the box is $\color{red}{red}$.

---

**My answer** is that using the definition of Conditional Probability.

First answer =  $ \dfrac {\dfrac{1}{3}}{\dfrac{2}{3}} $ Since $P(A \cap B) $ =$\dfrac{1}{3} $ Probability of choosing A and $P(B)=\dfrac{2}{3} $ since it contains both cases with A and B being drawn.

However for the second question the answer will be $\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{3}}{\dfrac{1}{3} \times 1 + \dfrac{1}{3} \times \dfrac{1}{2}} $ = $ \dfrac{2}{3} $.

Am i correct in this steps?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this by reformulating the problems.

In the first problem (supposing it is to be read that a chest is chosen that contains at least one red ball) the condition simply rules out chest C, so a random chest among A,B is chosen; given a uniform probability this chooses A with probability $\frac12$.

In the second problem, the actual experiment is not choosing a chest, but choosing a chest and then choosing a ball. Given that every chest contains the same number of balls, assuming a uniform probability both for choosing the chest and for choosing the ball, one has a uniform probability on the set of all balls. So one has chosen a ball at random, and found a red ball; the conditional probability corresponds to choosing a *red* ball uniformly at random and checking the chest it came from. Given that $2$ out of $3$ red balls are in chest A, the probability of obtaining chest A is $\frac23$.

So your outcomes are indeed correct.